# Normal distribution × x-axis values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If we take the Gaussian function
$$y = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
and now multiply by $x$ like this:
$$y = \frac x{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
What have we achieved? It looks like another Gaussian when plotted, but it narrows and shifts to the right. Is there a name for what has been done here? I have come across this distribution by weighting a histogram which has a normal distribution by the values on its $x$-axis.

Comment: What if $\mu < 0$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Then the mean is simply negative.

Comment: @Parclytaxel and so is the alleged "distribution" on the negative axis

Comment: @DilipSarwate I meant the old one, not the new one. My answer should clear things up.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The point is that if $\mu < 0$, the alleged distribution has negative value when $x < 0$ (and the negative axis is where most of the probability mass lies). So wondering whether the alleged distribution is valid or not is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new function is not a probability distribution. Instead, its integral over the whole real line gives the *expected value* of the normal distribution, which is well-known to be $\mu$.

Besides that, there does not seem to be any meaning assigned to the new function.

Comment: Thanks - can the centre and width of the new function (is it still a normal distribution?) be easily derived?

Comment: @fdawg The new distribution won't be normal at all. It is symmetric only if $\mu=0$.